# mysql case function

Tags: mysql

I have following query and it is updating MAC address which are missing hyphnes but for the other who alerady have them it is changing them to null.  Try to update values in one column.

```
UPDATE mytable SET MAC =
CASE
 WHEN MAC NOT LIKE '%-%' 
  THEN UPPER(CONCAT(SUBSTR(MAC,1,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,3,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,5,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,7,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,9,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,11,2)))
 END;
```

Any suggestions woild be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just add an `ELSE` case which sets the value to its current value:

```
UPDATE mytable SET MAC =
CASE
 WHEN MAC NOT LIKE '%-%' 
  THEN UPPER(CONCAT(SUBSTR(MAC,1,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,3,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,5,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,7,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,9,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,11,2)))
  /* Else case sets it to its current value to avoid NULL */
  ELSE MAC
 END;
```

It's also possible to use a `WHERE` clause so rows that should not be updated are not matched in the first place. That is probably the more appropriate action to take in this instance, unless you have other conditions to apply in the `CASE`

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET MAC = UPPER(CONCAT(SUBSTR(MAC,1,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,3,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,5,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,7,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,9,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,11,2)))
WHERE MAC NOT LIKE '%-%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE mytable 

SET MAC = UPPER(CONCAT(SUBSTR(MAC,1,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,3,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,5,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,7,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,9,2),'-', SUBSTR(MAC,11,2)))

WHERE  MAC NOT LIKE '%-%'
```